# custom break function in handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

In the code below, i have defined a custom break helper for handlebars. The custom break function has been developed using for loop to iterate over array objects. But, the break helper is not generic in nature and is specific to a particular array. How to define a generic custom break helper ?

```
<!-- required handlebars: -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.1/handlebars.min.js"></script>


<!-- handlebars template: -->
  <script id="handlebars-demo" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#break students}}
     {{name}} has passed in {{passingYear}}.<br>
  {{/break}}      
  </script>

<div id="placeholder"></div>

<script>
//context object:
var context = {
  "students": [
    {
      "name": "student1",
      "passingYear": 2016
    },    
    {
      "name": "student2",
      "passingYear": 2018 
    },
     { 
      "name": "student3",
      "passingYear": 2013
    },
     {
      "name": "student4",
      "passingYear": 2019
    }

  ]
} 
//defining customized "break" helper in handlebars:

Handlebars.registerHelper("break", function(data,options) {
  var len = data.length;
  var returnData = "";

//custom break function:

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if(data[i].passingYear>2015){
        document.write(returnData + options.fn(data[i]));
} else {

        document.write(returnData + options.fn(data[i]));
        i=len+1;
      }
  }
});
//set variable template to handlebars-demo id in test.html:
var template = $('#handlebars-demo').html();
// Handlebars compiles the above template variable into a templateScript:
var templateScript = Handlebars.compile(template);
// context object is passed to above templateScript:
var html = templateScript(context);
//setting html to output:
$("#placeholder").append(html);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var context = {
  "students": [{
      "name": "mrinal",
      "passingYear": 2013
    },
    {
      "name": "raman",
      "passingYear": 2016
    },
    {
      "name": "John",
      "passingYear": 2018
    }
  ]
}

var context2 = ["mrinal","raman","John"];

Handlebars.registerHelper("break", function(array, field, operator, breakvalue, options) {
  var arrayLength = array.length;
  var returnData="";
  var fieldValue = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
      if (field === '.') {
        fieldValue=array[i];
      } else {
        fieldValue=array[i][field];
      }
      if ((operator == "eq" && fieldValue == breakvalue) ||
         (operator == "ne" && fieldValue != breakvalue) ||
          (operator == "gt" && fieldValue > breakvalue) ||
          (operator == "le" && fieldValue <= breakvalue) ||
          (operator == "ge" && fieldValue >= breakvalue) ||
          (operator == "lt" && fieldValue < breakvalue)) {
        returnData = returnData + options.fn(array[i]);
      } else {
        return  returnData;
      }
  }
  return  returnData;
});

var template = $('#handlebars-demo').html();
var templateScript = Handlebars.compile(template);
var html = templateScript(context2);
$("#placeholder").append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.1/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<script id="handlebars-demo" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#break this '.' 'ne' 'raman'}}{{this}} has passed.<br>{{/break}}
</script>

<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191515/discussion-on-answer-by-christophe-thiry-custom-break-function-in-handlebars).